# What are the phrases that I can paint?

Tags: the-talos-principle

What is the full list of phrases, which I can paint with [the Paint Can](http://thetalosprinciple.gamepedia.com/The_Paint_Can) in The Talos Principle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in the game files, you can open `Content/Talos/All_01.gro` as a zip file. Then have a look at `Content/Talos/Databases/TalosMessages.txt`, this file contains all the possible QR code messages.

In the *PlayerMessages* category you will find the 45 messages a player can paint :

```
It feels as if I've been struggling with these problems for days. Did you take so long?
Elohim keeps telling me I'm doing well, but these puzzles are simply impossible.
Don't worry. If you're anything like me you just need to take your time and the solutions will present themselves.
How am I expected to solve these problems when my existence is so limited?
I hope wherever I am to go next the obstacles in my way will be less trivial.
They say that Elohim's Messengers will come to the aid of those in need. I say avoid being in need of their help in the first place.
Elohim's Messengers will aid those in need. Seek them out in the secret halls.
I have gathered every sigil I could find in this land, but I fear there may be some that are hidden from sight.
Don't bother going any further. I'm way ahead of you already.
I solved this one in about 20 seconds. Get on with it.
Where do you think you're going? You don't want to go down there. Trust me.
You'll be needing a special device to solve this one.
Have you tried crossing the laser beams?
This is without a doubt the hardest problem I encountered.
There is more to this place than it seems. I have seen things you can only imagine.
I am not the first one to undertake these trials, that much is clear. If you are reading this then neither will I have been the last.
Sometimes you have to find the courage to break down the barriers. With an axe.
I have heard all the lady in the light had to say. I can't help but feel we have lost so much more than we have retained.
I have travelled to the edge of the known world. Though it seems to stretch on forever, our domain is much less than we imagined.
I have now travelled this land extensively, and I can say without hesitation that this is the most beautiful spot.
Elohim lied about the tower. I stepped foot inside and returned to tell the tale.
The tools to overcome this place have been provided to us. We need only learn how to use them.
Stay true to your path, for wondrous powers are granted those who progress the furthest.
Words are merely an obstacle to action. Don't talk, act.
The truth is hidden in the words, but it’s up to you to find it. Read. Think.
The certification program is a sham. What does a computer know about humanity?
There is no way to beat the certification program. It's all lies.
There must be a way to escape this place. Help me to find it.
I asked the serpent its name. It told me it was called Milton.
There are those in this place who can be reasoned with. Seek them out and strike a deal. It worked for me.
Do not trust the serpent. Its words of doubt are easily overcome.
Am I going crazy or do the computer terminals have a personality?
If anyone reads this - meet me at the top of the tower.
I have no idea what's going on. Do you?
It's clear there is a higher power at work here. We need only do as we are commanded.
Frogs are people too.
We all meander around this labyrinth trying to solve its puzzles, but we must remember it is the good of all that matters, not the triumph of one.
We all meander around this labyrinth trying to solve its puzzles, but we must remember that no matter how far any one of us progresses, we all remain equal.
We all meander around this labyrinth trying to solve its puzzles, but we must remember it is not the outcome that matters, but the reasons for our actions in the first place.
Everyone here will try to convince you their way of seeing things is right. Only when you realise there is no right will you truly be free.
My ideals have been called into question more than once, as yours will be too. None of that matters provided you remember that YOU are all that matters.
Do not be afraid to doubt.
Every force in this world is some extreme or another. The trick is to carve out a path between them.
ELOHIM spoke truly. I have been given eternal life. Have faith!
ELOHIM lies! You will not find eternal life, only damnation. Doubt everything!
```

This file also contains all the QR codes pre-written on the walls, secret QR codes, help QR codes...